# Handling pin modes from devicetree to module

Tags: linux, kernel-module, device-tree

I am trying to write a linux device driver for a SPI device, using Atmels SAMA5d35 MPU. Linux version is 4.19.30.

I have configured the pins in my device tree and set the status to "okay". 
After that the pins changed mode as expected. My question is then, how do I manipulate pinmodes during runtime? My SPI device is not always on, neither is my driver always loaded. When that is the case I want the configured SPI pins to change mode to normal GPIOs (for power-consumption).

Is it the drivers task to do that, or is it something one can define in the device tree, when the driver for example is not loaded?

I have tried to implement a pinctrl-0 for setting the pins to SPI mode, and then a pinctrl-1 for setting the same pins to normal GPIOs. My idea was to switch between these pin configuration in the device driver, but unfortunately the device tree complaints about using the same pins for both pinctrl-0 and pinctrl-1 (compiles fine, but system wont boot). Although this was just my logical thoughts. I am sure there is a more correct way to do the things I stated above.

```
        spi0: spi@f0004000 {
            status = "okay";

            ext_adc: ads1258@1 {
                compatible = "ti,ads1258";
                pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
                pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_spi0_default>;
                pinctrl-1 = <&pinctrl_spi0_sleep>;
                reg = <1>;                                  /* Hardware chipselect SPI0_NPCS1 */
                spi-max-frequency = <16000000>;             /* According to datasheet */
                start-gpios = <&pioD 5 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
                drdy-gpios = <&pioD 22 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
                enaadc-gpios = <&pioA 26 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>; 
            };
        };
```

Comment: Pin control framework operates on states. You have defined two of them. So, using such names you may tell pin control to switch pins of the certain device to the predefined certain mode.

Comment: That was my thought as well. But when I define more than 1 state, the system won't boot. I know it is a custom made bootlader, which is initiating the device tree as well. I think therein the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is then, how do I manipulate pinmodes during runtime?

That's called "Runtime pinmuxing", which is described in [**Documentation/pinctrl.txt**](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/pinctrl.txt).
But you may not have to do that.

> When that is the case I want the configured SPI pins to change mode to normal GPIOs (for power-consumption).
>
> Is it the drivers task to do that, or is it something one can define in the device tree, when the driver for example is not loaded?

The default mode for a pin (of Atmel/Microchip SoCs) is to be unassigned to any peripheral mode, and be available for use as a GPIO.
All pins that are not assigned to a peripheral or acquired by a driver as a GPIO, end up in the pool of available GPIOs.

So when your SPI driver is not successfully installed, those pins it would use will be in the pool of available GPIOs.

> I have tried to implement a pinctrl-0 for setting the pins to SPI mode, and then a pinctrl-1 for setting the same pins to normal GPIOs.

Assigning pins for use by the SPI controller is proper, but there is no mechanism AFAIK for assigning a pin to be an available GPIO.

You can only define properties in the DT for what a device, such as the SPI controller, requires.
There is no mechanism for an "alternate" assignment.

> I am sure there is a more correct way to do the things I stated above.

If your driver does not install, then its resources such as its pins should not be allocated.  The pins that the SPI would have used will remain unused, and end up in the pool of available GPIOs (unless something else claims/requests one of those pins).
So your DT needs to simply define what your device uses, and leave it at that.

If you still want your driver to modify the state of its pin, then study the section titled "Pin control requests from drivers" in [**Documentation/pinctrl.txt**](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/pinctrl.txt).